# Does common text cause duplicate content?

Tags: duplicate-content

Working on a new website, that has lots of pages with people's info and bio. Because of this, it contains a lot of common text on each person's page.

`example.com/person1` contains:

- Height: his height
- Weight:his weight
- Country: USA/etc
- Birthday:
- Age:

And lots of other common fields.

`example.com/person2` contains all of the same fields but with different values.

Each page has on the top a few paragraphs describing that person, but all the other fields are the same.

Could this cause duplicate content? As the same fields/words are on each and every page.

Answer (score 1):

Such pages would be spotted rather as thin content and soft-404, as duplicated content. I would `noindex` them.

Comment: But as i said , there is a different description on each page. But under the description there are these standard fields. These sections are about 20% of the total text on that page. But it is always the same as on the other pages.

Comment: I'd strongly take Evgeniy's advice unless your description on each page is substantially different compared to the rest of the pages. I'd also use a website to check pages for duplicate content. Siteliner is good but it only checks a site once a month for free.